# how to pass the data of a more than one text widget to a list of strings based on index of text widget in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching the data from firestore via StreamBuilder in the form of a ListView containing of text widgets. I want to pass the data of each text widget to a separate string using toString(). How to convert each text widget to string separately based on the index?

```
Widget download(){
return StreamBuilder(
 stream: Firestore.instance.collection('branch11').snapshots(),
 builder: (context,snapshot){
  if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
   return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
      DocumentSnapshot subjects= snapshot.data.documents[index];
       return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('${subjects['download']}'),
      ],);
    },);
 },
);

String pdfUrl = download().toString();
```

[Firestore image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9qb9.png)

[Snapshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmaZd.png)

Comment: please add more explain !!

Comment: the listview contains of text widgets whose data is fetched from firestore collection "branch11". What I want to do is convert those text widgets to strings using toString(). Suppose there are 4 text widgets in the listview, I want them to be converted to 4 different strings but not just one string.

Comment: and 'download' is key of your field ?? if can add your firestore snapshot image

Comment: yes, 'download' is key of my field which contains a url

Comment: when a user clicks on download/preview button, he is redirected  to a new screen consisting of webview for which the initial url is fetched from the firestore in the form of text widgets in listview. The thing is I want to convert those text widgets to strings but I don't get it how to convert those text widgets to strings, because there will be more than one text widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i think you must **ListTile** or another widget (Image,Raw..etc) as widget builder not another **ListView** inside another **ListView** !!

so your code will be like that as simple and **onTap** callback every download when user click on item   , if you want make more complex widget  just replace ListTile with new widget

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('branch11').snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            DocumentSnapshot subjects= snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return  ListTile(
              title: Text(subjects['name']),
              onTap: (){
                String downloadUrl = subjects['download'];
                String name= subjects['name'];

                debugPrint("name at $index =$name");
                 debugPrint("downloadUrl at $index =$downloadUrl");

                //do what you want here
              },
            );
          },);
      },
    );
```

**to send data between screen** 
-Make the SecondScreen constructor take a parameter for the type of data that you want to send to it. In this particular example, the data is defined to be a String value and is set here with this.text

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  SecondScreen({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  ...
```

Then use the Navigator in the FirstScreen widget to push a route to the SecondScreen widget. You put the data that you want to send as a parameter in its constructor.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SecondScreen(text: 'Hello',),
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It did solve my major problem but how do I pass the data of downloadUrl string to another screen?

Comment: @youtubegamer im edit the answer , please make my answer as correct if help you

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I was making it complicated, but you solved it in a simple way.